# Replace text with image in PDF using Telerik RadPdfProcessing

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, telerik

I'm using Telerik RadPdfProcessing for Xamarin to customize a PDF document in a mobile application.
The code must search for a "#placeholder#" inside the document and replace it with the signature hand typed by the user.

The signature image can be inserted at a given position with this code:

```
RadFixedPage last = document.Pages.Last();
FixedContentEditor editor = new FixedContentEditor(last);
editor.Position.Translate(400, 900);
editor.DrawImage(imageSource);
```

And I've found a [forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/walk-through-the-page-to-find-a-certain-text-string) saying that find in page is basically not supported by the library, since it allows only to search one character at a time:

```
foreach (var contentElement in last.Content) {
    if (contentElement is TextFragment) {
        TextFragment fragment = (TextFragment) contentElement;
        string text = fragment.Text;

        //** THIS DOESN'T WORK! **
        //if ("#placeholder#" == text)  {
        //    fragment.Text = "";
        //    editor.Position = fragment.Position;
        //    editor.DrawImage(imageSource);
        //}
    }
}
```

Does anyone have more recent news on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in the following way:

```
RadFixedPage lastPage = document.Pages.Last();

IPosition position = new SimplePosition();

foreach (ContentElementBase contentElement in lastPage.Content.ToList())
{
    if (contentElement is TextFragment fragment)
    {
        if (fragment.Text == "#placeholder#")
        {
            position = fragment.Position;
            lastPage.Content.Remove(fragment);
        }
    }
}

ImageSource imageSource;
using (FileStream source = File.Open("image1.jpg", FileMode.Open))
{
    imageSource = new ImageSource(source);
}

FixedContentEditor editor = new FixedContentEditor(lastPage);
editor.Position = position;
editor.DrawImage(imageSource, new Size(50, 50));
```

Another option could be to replace a predefined [Field](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radwordsprocessing/concepts/fields/fields) by searching for its name. This way you can pre-allocate space on the document's page.

```
RadFixedPage firstPage = document.Pages[0];

Annotation field = firstPage.Annotations.First(a => ((VariableContentWidget)a).Field.Name == "SampleField");
System.Windows.Rect fieldRect = field.Rect;

string imagePath = "image1.jpg";
ImageSource imageSource;
using (FileStream source = File.Open(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    imageSource = new ImageSource(source);
}

IPosition position = new SimplePosition();
simplePosition.Translate(fieldRect.X, fieldRect.Y);

Image image = new Image
{
    ImageSource = imageSource,
    Position = position,
    Width = fieldRect.Width,
    Height = fieldRect.Height
};

firstPage.Annotations.Remove(field);
firstPage.Content.Add(image);
```

Comment: Martin, thank you for your suggestions. For some reason, the foreach loop on content elements isn't returning what I'm expecting, but it can be a problem of  a specific document. I tested it on other items and it works! Thank you also for the second option, which unfortunately doesn't apply to my case, since I haven't fields.